# ArrayList doesn't add a new entry

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new here and I got a small problem I hope some of you guys could help me with.
My program gives a string like this (c,e);(e,c);(c,e);(e,d);(d,c);(c,a);(a,b);(b,c); into my method. Right now the method looks like this

```
public static Boolean compare(String Sequence) {
    Boolean NotUnique = true;
    ArrayList<String> AmountOfSequences = new ArrayList<String>(12870);
    NotUnique = AmountOfSequences.contains(Sequence);
    if (NotUnique == false) {
        AmountOfSequences.add();
        System.out.println(AmountOfSequences);
    }

    return (NotUnique);

}
```

The idea is to make sure that every solution to the problem only appears once but for some reason it seems to replace the previous entry so that it kind of negates the reason the Method even exists. I'd be glad for any help.

Comment: this code doesn´t even compile. How is this related to your titles question then?

Comment: @godisalie92 please be a good stackoverflow citizen and accept the answer which you fond most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the ArrayList as a local variable of that method, so every call creates a new instance. Make it a static member :

```
private static ArrayList<String> AmountOfSequences = new ArrayList<String>(12870);

public static Boolean compare(String Sequence) {
    Boolean NotUnique = true;
    NotUnique = AmountOfSequences.contains(Sequence);
    if (NotUnique == false) {
        AmountOfSequences.add(Sequence);
        System.out.println(AmountOfSequences);
    }

    return (NotUnique);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it simpler by using a set. See comments:

```
    //A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements.
    private static Collection<String> AmountOfSequences = new  HashSet<String>(12870);

    public static Boolean add(String Sequence) {

         //add returns true if the collection changed (Sequence added to it)
         return ! AmountOfSequences.add(Sequence);

    }
```